# Tkinter app with matplotlib Canvas refuse to stop

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, canvas

I created this app which works but refuses to let the program go after closing the Tkinter window :

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

import sys
import random

import tkinter as Tk

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)


root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Stade knn algorithm")

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)

nb_NS = 50
k = 3
supp,lineA,lineB = initialize()

# a tk.DrawingArea
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Full code here : https://www.codepile.net/pile/6xzlZoJW

Comment: Run in python or Ipython?

Comment: I run it in python @lalala

Comment: Why are you calling: `canvas._tkcanvas.pack(...)`? Isn't the `canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(...)` supposed to do the trick?

Comment: You're right, it's a mistake from my side, I changed that. But this doesn't solve my problem.  @TheLizzard

Comment: Can you use `fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure()` instead of `fig = plt.figure()`?

Comment: Change `fig = plt.figure()` to `fig = plt.Figure()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that closing the window (apparently) doesn't take you out of the mainloop.

From what I see either put everything in a class or add
`root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", sys.exit)` before `root.mainloop()`.